# Why does HttpSessionState not implement IDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session, dictionary

[HttpSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx) appears to be a typical key -> value collection, so why does it not implement the [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s4ys34ea.aspx)-Interface?

Background: I am trying to output/save the Context of my ASP.NET Website when an error occurs and wanted to do this with a recursive function, that outputs a Collection and all containing Collections. Because `HttpSessionState` only implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`, I am losing the information about the keys if I want to do it in a generic manner (= working with interfaces).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IDictionary` implies that the target collection is capable of quick lookups by key. (As far as I am aware) `HttpSessionState` is just a list of items, not a dictionary style structure. As a search of that structure would take linear time there's no reason to treat it as a dictionary. If you need a lot of quick lookups then copy the keys and values into a true dictionary. If you don't need quick lookups, then you'll just need to specialize for that class.

There are more things to an interface than just a list of method prototypes. There are semantics that need to be preserved for an interface too. Quick lookups by key is one such non-explicit assumption for (most) consumers of any `IDictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

How about writing your own IDictionary-implementing wrapper that takes an HttpSessionState object in its constructor and behaves as you want? I'm assuming you want to do this so you can swap out other kinds of name-value (IDictionary-implementing) session implementations.

Of course, as Billy points out, this is a great way to dress a poor-performing psuedo-dictionary in dictionary clothes!

Answer (score -1):

Just loop through the [Session Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.keys.aspx) and reference values like so:

```
Session[key]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It doesn't answer my question, though. I still couldn't write a general function for the output then, that works for other cases/collections too. I would have to cast to HttpSessionState to make this work.

Comment: And it still does not explain why the .NET team chose not to use the interface here. I'm curious. ;)